# How to perform a VB vlookup from a userform entry

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a script for a invoice, that can perform a vlookup based on the entry in a userform. I have a userform, which has a combobox with a named range. I would like four text boxes, which display the result of the vlookup.
I have a vlookup set up, which just goes into the normal cell in the worksheet. it is:

```
 =VLOOKUP($A22,Products!$A$1:$B$1679,2,FALSE)
```

I would like it, so that rather than looking for cell A22, it performs the vlookup from the combobox, which is just named test. I would then like to repeat it for:

```
 =VLOOKUP($A47,Products!$A$2:$A$1679,1,FALSE)

 =VLOOKUP($A47,Products!$A$2:$A$1679,1,FALSE)

  =VLOOKUP($A47,Products!$A$2:$C$1679,3,FALSE)
```

Thanks for reading, and I hope that you can help. If you could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the combobox control's `.Value` property, pseudo-code:

```
 =VLOOKUP(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value,Products!$A$2:$A$1679,1,FALSE)
```

Etc.

Actual code:

```
Dim lookupRange as Range
Set lookupRange = Worksheets("Products").Range("A2:A1679")

Product = Application.Vlookup(UserForm1.Selectprodcutcombo.Value‌​, _
            lookupRange, 1, False)
```

Of course, you will need to modify the name of your form and combobox, based on your form's design.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added this to the vb script, but am now getting am now getting a compile error, due to a invalid character. Is there anything that you notice that is wrong?                                   Product=Application.worksheetfunction.VLOOKUP(UserForm1.Selectprodcutcombo.Value,Products!$A$2:$A$1679,1,FALSE)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Will look forward to testing it.